# Pywinauto grabbing text from window

Tags: python, pywinauto

I correctly found my window with pywinauto.
[image]

that's the window i want to grab info from. i want to grab the text below "Log", aka everything in the thing where it's currently "Listening..."
current code =

```html
>>> import pywinauto
>>> app = pywinauto.Application().start('TerminalManager.exe')
>>> dlg_spec = app.TerminalManager
>>> dlg_spec = app.window(title='Terminal Manager v3.8')
>>> dlg_spec
<pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification object at 0x05A99B90>
```

It does find it, help would be greatly appreciated. The text in the bottom is selectable by dragging mouse + can control c + control V it, i'd just like to have it without having it in the foreground.

Comment: Can you provide the download link for Terminal Manager v3.8? I couldn't find it quickly. Of course, if this project is free / open source. Or I need a Spy++ screenshot for "Logs" subwindow as a target.

Comment: well yea i could send you the file on discord if you give me your discord? since i doubt the devs will be happy if i send you it like this on stackoverflow

Comment: Understood. If you need an NDA, no problem. My gmail: `"vasily-v-ryabov".replace("-", ".")`

Comment: My Discord tag: #8992